# retrieve all attendee data when an event data is selected from a joined registration model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I've been stuck on this for almost 2 days now, I've been trying to solve the problem but I can't seem to get the data I want.

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET. I want to get all the attendee for a certain event whenever I click the details (link) of an event.

I think I got the logic right, but I can't seem to write it up in code.

This is my `details.cshtml` file:

```
@model MVCUML.Models.Registration

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
<h4>Registration</h4>
<hr />
@Html.DisplayForModel(Model.Events.EventName)
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayForModel(Model.Attendees.Name) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
</div>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

This is my controller for Registration/Details:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Registration registration = db.Registrations.Find(id);

        if (registration == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(registration);
}
```

---

```
namespace MVCUML.Models
{
    public class Registration
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EventId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AttendeeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Event Events { get; set; }
        public virtual Attendee Attendees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Event
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Event Name")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Event Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public Decimal Fee { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventAssignment> EventAssignments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Attendee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FName, this.LName); }
    }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class RegistrationIndexData
{
    public IEnumerable<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your foreach loop code with the following code and give it a try:

```
<table>
     @foreach (var evtReg in Model.Events.Registrations)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@evtReg.Attendees.Name </td>
                </tr>
            }
  </table>
```

Also, I suggest rename your `Events` and `Attendees` to singular names like `Event` and `Attendee` properties on `Registration` class as these properties hold on object and not list of objects

Comment: Thank You @mohsin ! i think i've almost got the output i desire. In debugging it shows up the number of attendees for an event. but at the same time its bypassing or ignoring this line of code `<td>@Html.DisplayForModel(evtReg.Attendees.Name) </td>`. it outputs this instead: 
Id
1
EventId
2
AttendeeId
4
Id
1
EventId
2
AttendeeId
4
Id
1
EventId
2
AttendeeId
4
Id
1
EventId
2
AttendeeId
4

Comment: @V.Brar I have updated the answer. But you got the idea about looping over Event registrations to display attendees.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it! a little tweak on code was needed

instead of this

```
<td>@Html.DisplayForModel(evtReg.Attendees.Name) </td>
```

i changed it to:

```
<td>@evtReg.Attendee.Name</td>
```

And it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!